# Pandas - Copying to Index and Then Sorting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am working on a large dataset of stock data. I've been able to create a multi-indexed dataframe, but now I can't configure it the way I want it.

Basically, I am trying to make an index called 'DATE' and then sort each smaller set against the index.

Right now it looks like this:

```
+------------+----------+-------+-------------+-------+
|    DATE    |   AAPL   |       |     GE      |       |
+------------+----------+-------+-------------+-------+
| DATE       | date     | close | date        | close |
| 05-31-2019 | 05/31/19 | 203   | 04-31-2019  | 9.3   |
| 05-30-2019 | 05/30/19 | 202   | 04-30-2019  | 9.3   |
| 05-29-2019 | 05/29/19 | 4     | 04-29-2019  | 9.6   |
|            |          |       |             |       |
| ...        |          |       |             |       |
|            |          |       |             |       |
| NaN        | NaN      | NaN   | 01/30/1970  | 0.77  |
| NaN        | NaN      | NaN   | 01/29/1970  | 0.78  |
| NaN        | NaN      | NaN   | 01/28/1970  | 0.76  |
+------------+----------+-------+-------------+-------+
```

Where DATE is the index.

And I want it to look like this:

```
+------------+----------+-------+----------+-------+
|    DATE    |   AAPL   |       |    GE    |       |
+------------+----------+-------+----------+-------+
| DATE       | date     | close | date     | close |
| 05-31-2019 | 05/31/19 | 203   | NaN      | NaN   |
| 05-30-2019 | 05/30/19 | 202   | NaN      | NaN   |
| 05-29-2019 | 05/29/19 | 4     | NaN      | NaN   |
|            |          |       |          |       |
| ...        |          |       |          |       |
|            |          |       |          |       |
| 01/30/1970 | NaN      | NaN   |01/30/1970| 0.77  |
| 01/29/1970 | NaN      | NaN   |01/29/1970| 0.78  |
| 01/28/1970 | NaN      | NaN   |01/28/1970| 0.76  |
+------------+----------+-------+----------+-------+
```

Where the index (DATE) has taken all of the unique values, and then all of the rows within stock symbols have moved to match the index where 'date' = 'DATE'.

I've tried so many attempts at this, but no matter what I can't figure out either one. I can't figure out how to make the Index a list of all of the unique 'date' values. And I can't figure out how to reformat the symbol data to match the new index.

A lot of my troubles (I suspect) have to do with the fact that I am using a multi-index for this, which makes everything more difficult as Pandas needs to know what level to be using.

I made the initial Index using this code:

```
df['DATE','DATE'] = df.xs(('AAPL', 'date'), level=('symbol', 'numbers'),   axis=1)
df.set_index('DATE', inplace=True)
```

I tried to make one that kept adding unique values to the column, like this:

```
for f in filename_wo_ext: 
    data = df.xs([f, 'date'], level=['symbol', 'numbers'], axis=1)
    df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
    df['DATE','DATE'] = data
    pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([df], columns=['DATE']) for f in     filename_wo_ext], ignore_index=True)
```

But that didn't cycle and append in the for loop that I wanted it to, it just made a column based on the last symbol.

Then in terms of sorting the symbol frame to match the index, I still haven't been able to figure that out.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why not prefer columns `['company', 'date', 'price', ...]`?

Comment: I made it a multi index so that I could easily select by 'symbol' (or company as you put it). If there was a column for each company, it would be difficult to select which 'price' I need.

Comment: `df.loc[df['company'] == 'company', 'price']`

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really solve my problem. I'm trying to preserve the multiindex format for now